# Copy columns from one table to another

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables suppose `TABLE_1` and `TABLE_2`. I have `a,b,c` columns in `TABLE_1` and `x,y,z` columns in `TABLE_2`. I want to copy only table structure from `TABLE_2` and add it to `TABLE_1` so my final table `TABLE_1` would be like `a,b,c,x,y,z`. How can I do this.

I don't want to have alter table then have defination of each single column then add it to 'table_1'.

Is it possible to do in mysql with single query ??

Comment: How does table 2 relate to table 1?

Comment: Create Table Table_1And2 Select ... will get you close. However you are implying a join, but you haven't said what on.

Comment: @strawberry. There is no relation between table. I just want to concatinate field of second table to first table.

Comment: @Sankalp, I understand you only want to create **empty** columns in `table_1` with the same definitions as some columns from `table_2`. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: If you dont want alter the table you can 1.create temp table 2.using alter table add column add the column names .

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible in *one* query.

You could however write a pure SQL procedure to do it (by inspecting the `information_schema` database), but this is not trivial, and probably not worth the hassle.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways, sure, but if there's no relation between the tables, **DON'T DO IT!**

It's no problem to have multiple tables, you know?

And even if there is a relation, as long as it's not a 1:1 relation (not even then necessarily, depends...), I wouldn't recommend it either. I suggest you read up a bit on database design and normalization forms.